# How to create Web application using Xamarin Forms(UWP) and C# in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, xamarin, .net-core, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I want to create a web application using Xamarin forms and c#. I am using .NET core 3.1 architecture. I am completely new to both these technologies.
I am not sure If we can create Web application UI using Xamarin forms(UWP). I saw several posts where only android, ios and windows mobile Applications are created using Xamarin but Is it possible to create ***UI for*** ***Desktop***?
I created few web pages and tried to run the project and all I see is "welcome to Xamarin!" screen.
Why I am not able to see the UI ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcKH3.png)

Comment: XF is NOT a web technology.  There are many other .NET platforms you can use to create web apps.

Comment: Use blazor webassembly, it's c# to

Comment: @Jason I have to use Xamarin Forms only as per client requirement for UI development as it is cross platform. but I am facing problem while creating windows desktop UI, I am not able to see the output, just the welcome screen.

Comment: @Trupti Like Json said, Xamarin.Forms is used for building iOS, Android, and Windows apps. You could try to use `Ooui`. The sample code i forkec maybe helpful. https://github.com/WendyZang/MyFirstOouiApp

Comment: if you are having a problem with a Forms UWP app, you should ask a question specifically about that problem and provide details including the relevant code.  The question that you actually asked was about using Forms to create Web applications.

Answer (score 2):

A bit Late, but [Ooui](https://github.com/praeclarum/Ooui) is all you need.
It creates an web version of your Xamarin Forms application.